# Object required error in running an excel macro from a text box

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error as "Object required" while running the macro which i have assigned to a text box.

I have copied the macro from another excel which has only one sheet. This is working fine there and generating the insert script based on the data in the sheet.

This macro i am inserting it in another workbook in the 4th sheet (this workbook has 4 sheets).
Below is the macro used :

```
Sub GetInsertSQL()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = wsSrc.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim LastCol As Long: LastCol = wsSrc.UsedRange.Find("*", Sear chOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strQuery = ""
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        strQuery = strQuery + "[" + CStr(wsSrc.Cells(1, j)) + "], "
    Next j
    strQuery = Left(strQuery, Len(strQuery) - 2)
    strQuery = "insert into [" + wsSrc.Name + "] (" + strQuery + ")"
    strOutput = strQuery + Chr(13) + Chr(10) + "values"

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        strQuery = ""
        'Adding this if condition to check if value in 1st column is New
        If (LCase(wsSrc.Cells(i, 1).Text) = "new") Then
            For j = 2 To LastCol
                strQuery = strQuery + "'" + Replace(CStr(wsSrc.Cells(i, j).Text), "'", "''") + "', "
            Next j

            strQuery = "(" + Left(strQuery, Len(strQuery) - 2) + "), "
            strOutput = strOutput + Chr(13) + Chr(10) + strQuery
        End If
    Next i

    strOutput = Left(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 2)
    OutputForm.txtOutput.Text = strOutput
    OutputForm.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

Is it something with the way i am doing a copy and paste ?

Comment: To concatenate strings in VBA, use the `&` character instead of `+`. Which statement is giving you the error?

Comment: This code is running fine in the original excel sheet which has only one sheet. the problem is coming when i copied to to another workbook in sheet 4 . How do i know which line has error? I tried to debug it but it didn't show any specif line which has error . Just got the final error after last step

Comment: With no other information, my suggestion is to stop using `ActiveSheet` and explicitly name the correct worksheet you want to operate with.

Comment: I tried using  Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = Sheets("Control-m Ref") but this also is giving me the same error. Is this correct to refer to the sheet name Control-m ref?

Comment: If `Control-m ref` is the name of the worksheet, then yes that is correct. My only other question is what is `OutputForm` and did you copy that over to the new workbook?